# CSS3 - add class to fire an animation and remove class on completion

Tags: jquery, animation, css, addclass, removeclass

I have a div and when I click it jquery adds a class which starts an animation running.  When the animation stops (after 3 seconds) I want the class to be removed, so that when the div is clicked on again the animation will start over.

This is only testing and only Chrome browser at the moment.

Here is my CSS3:

```
.spin360
{
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin 
{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
    100%   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
}
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#spinButton').click(function () {
            $('#shape').addClass('spin360');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#spinButton').click(function () {
            $('#shape').addClass('spin360').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function () {
                $('#shape').removeClass('spin360');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#spinButton').click(function () {
            $('#shape').addClass('spin360');
        });

        $('#spinButton').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (e) {
            $('#shape').removeClass('spin360');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In all cases - my animation runs on the first click, but not subsequent clicks.

Comment: this might be related => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062105/webkit-transitionend-event-grouping

Comment: What version of Chrome/Safari/Webkit are you running? Your solution works fine for me in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BYfDZ/

Comment: @Pete You may want to take note that the webkitAnimationEnd seems to fire a few seconds after the animation has ended. So it may seem unresponsive when you test it.

Comment: Running Chrome 21.0.1180.60 beta-m.  I waited 10 secs and still not firing after first time.

Comment: Tried reverting to the non-beta version too but still not working (21.0.1180.60 m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an older version of jquery.

I updated to 1.8.0 and it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in a cross browser way as well:

```
$('#spinButton').bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function (e) {
    $('#shape').removeClass('spin360');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// works fine however you did leave our standard declaration
//so your code would only work on Chrome, Safari, Opera

> /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
>   @-webkit-keyframes spin  {
>       0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
>       100%   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
>   }
>
> /* Standard syntax */
>   @keyframes spin  {
>       0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
>       100%   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg); } 
>   }

Comment: I know, that's why I said "This is only testing and only Chrome browser at the moment.".