# Add/Remove a class to a div on every click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add a class to a 'div' on click, for CSS3 animations. But I also require to have that class removed after the animation is over.

I tried something like this but it does not work -

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    $('.class').removeClass("animate");
    $(this).addClass("animate");
});
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: you can use setTimeout to remove it after some time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Callback when CSS3 transition finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884563/jquery-remove-class-after-css-animation-played

Comment: **Duplicate:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784831/css3-add-class-to-fire-an-animation-and-remove-class-on-completion

Comment: Please use Google search first http://goo.gl/y16AW0 .. and try to avoid duplication

Comment: I searched a lot before posting the question, may be I was not able to find the right keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two immediate possibilites:

**1)**
Use a `setTimeout` function that fires after the animation is complete. To achieve this you should know how long the animation duration is:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var animDuration = 1000; //ms of the animation duration
    $(this).addClass("animate");
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("animate");
    }, animDuration);
});
```

**2)** A better solution is to add an eventListener on `animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd` that fires whenever the animation is actually complete. For this approach you do not need to know the duration of the animation.

EDIT: from `adeneo` and also some code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes):

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var animDuration = 1000; //ms of the animation duration
    $(this).addClass("animate");
    $(this).bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function () {
       $(this).removeClass('animate');
    });
});
```

The above code does almost what you say, "gets the duration dynamically". What it really does is listening for an event that fires when the animation is complete / finished. The reason for the multiple event listeners is because of browser compatibility, each browser fires its own event. (oAnimationEnd = Opera, MSAnimationEnd = IE etc)

Thanks: https://coderwall.com/p/hn7gsg

Comment: That was quick thanks! I will test it out. Between is there any way to get the animation duration dynamically? I guess I will have to use html5 'data-' attributes, right? But will it work with multiple buttons? Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate function for animation

```
   $('.class').click(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("animate");
        $('.class').animate($('.class').removeClass("animate"),2000);   
    });
```