# EmberJS: How to create modal forms

Tags: ember.js

Whats a good way or a pattern to creating modal forms in EmberJS. Something like [this](http://goo.gl/5Vgv9).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my modified [Bootstrap.ModalPane](https://github.com/pjlammertyn/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/packages/ember-bootstrap/lib/views/modal_pane.js)

ex:

```
App.ContactView = Bootstrap.ModalPane.extend({
  closeOnEscape: false,
  showBackdrop: true,
  showCloseButton: false,
  heading: 'Contact',
  primary: "Save changes",
  secondary: "Cancel",
  classNames: ["large-modal"],

  bodyViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'contact-body'
  }),  

  callback: function (opts, event) {
    var controller = this.get('controller');
    if (opts.primary) {
        controller.save();
    } else {
        controller.cancel();
    }    
  }
});
```

In you controller you can then do something like this:

```
editContact: function (contact) {
   var contactController = this.controllerFor('contact');
    contactController.set('content', contact);
    var contactView = App.ContactView.create({
        controller: contactController
    });
    contactView.append();
},
```

You can also define your own modalPaneTemplate with customizations. It's the principle of how the Boostrap.ModelPane works that matters, default it only supports 2 buttons at the bottom. If you want 5 buttons, or buttons in the header, start coding yourself and create a custom modalPaneTemplate.

Comment: You can perhaps extend it, and create your own custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I will describe the way i manage modal views with a CSS approach:

Add CSS class names:

```
.modal {

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform @modal-duration @ease-animation-style;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.modal.from-left.is-hidden {

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);

}

.modal.from-right.is-hidden {

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(320px,0,0);

}

.modal.from-up.is-hidden {

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-1*@app-height,0);

}

.modal.from-down.is-hidden {

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,@app-height,0);

}
```

Add custom events to your Application Namespace to receive the transitionEnd event in your view:

```
Yn.Application = Em.Application.extend( Em.Evented, {
  customEvents: {
    webkitTransitionEnd:  'transitionEnd',
    ......
  }
});
```

Now create a mixin to be used in your view as:

```
Yn.Modal = Em.Mixin.create({

  isHidden: true,
  classNameBindings: ['isHidden'],
  classNames: ['modal'],


  transitionEnd: function(event) {
    // transitionEnd triggers multiple times
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062105/webkit-transitionend-event-grouping

    if ( event.originalEvent.propertyName === '-webkit-transform' && 
        $(event.target)[0] === this.$()[0] ) {
      var eventName = this.get('isHidden') ? 'transitionHide' : 'transitionShow' ;
      this.trigger(eventName);
    }

  }

});
```

You can now insert the view in the DOM via appendTo or any handlebars view template or whatever method you use, and manages your view with its **isHidden** property which can be bound for example to a controller UI property, you could also interact with the view with the view lifecycle hooks as **didInsertElement** or the new defined as **transitionHide**, **transitionShow** hooks.